# Python Idle theme configuration

Tags: python, customization, python-idle

I've made my own custom themes for IDLE, I'm wondering if theres a way to make the Python IDLE and Shell windows transparent. I want my python theme to resemble everything I did to my TextMate theme and I have the colors already finished. 
Is this final step possible?

Comment: If you're going to be spending time customizing your coding environment to be exactly how you like it, why are you starting with something as crude as IDLE? Wouldn't it be simpler to use a [more robust editor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/2069350)?

Comment: with tkinter you can make whole windows transparent but not parts of them. This may not be built into IDLE. Have a look at how to make windows transparent.